# problem when i create branches in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vscode when i create new branch it keep giving me this messsage " sulemanhassan@Sulemans-MacBook flutter_catalog % /usr/bin/git -C "/Users/sulemanhassan/Downloads/Flutter/flutter_ catalog" -c "core.editor=code --wait --reuse-window" branch Day2 main fatal: not a valid object name: 'main' "

help me if someoe knows

Comment: show output of `git branch -avv` and `git status`.